# Plotly annotated heatmap axis order depends on data type

Tags: python, plotly, heatmap, factory, figure

I am trying to plot confusion matrices in Plotly using annotated heatmaps. Now I noticed that for some reason the Y axis gets flipped depending on the data type of labels, even when I force the datatype to strings.

The code below will provide two plots, of which the second plot has the inverted Y-axis compared to the first one. The first one is the way I would want to have it displayed, regardless of datatype of the class names.

Where does the order get changed and how do I force it to remain in the order of the list as provided?

'''

```
import numpy as np

confm = array([[10, 4,  0,  1,  0],
               [1, 20, 10,  1,  0],
               [0,  7, 30,  3,  0],
               [0,  1,  1, 40,  2],
               [1,  1,  2,  2, 50]])

labels = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]


import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.figure_factory as ff


def plot_matrix(confm, class_names):

    z =  np.round(confm, 2)  # for readability
    
    class_names = [str(c) for c in class_names]  # force all to string

    
    fig = ff.create_annotated_heatmap(z,
                                      colorscale='reds',
                                      xtype='array',
                                      ytype='array',
                                      x=class_names,
                                      y=class_names[::-1],  # invert order
                                     )
    
    

    fig.update_layout(
            title='Confusion matrix',
            width=600,
            height=600,
            margin=dict(pad=20),
            plot_bgcolor='white',
            xaxis=dict(title='Prediction',
                       showticklabels = True,
                       side='bottom',
                       tickmode='array',
                       tickvals=class_names,
                       ticktext=class_names),
            yaxis=dict(title='Truth',
                       tickmode='array',
                       tickvals=class_names,
                       ticktext=class_names[::-1])
                    )


    fig.show()


plot_matrix(confm, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
plot_matrix(confm, ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

It's clear **plotly** libraries are casting back to integer / number when possible.  To keep behaviour the same you can

```
    class_names = [str(c)+"\0" for c in class_names]  # force all to string
```

just append a **null** ascii character that then prevents it being cast back to a number.

Comment: This actually seems to create the exact opposite of the desired outcome (plus some undesirable ascii chars).

Also, the casting doesn't really work consistently, or logically: only the Y-axis is reordered, while the X-axis is left alone.

Comment: I'm using plotly 5.1.0,  both produce same chart with labels starting in top left corner.  The number labels just don't work,  plotly is trying to index from zero. BTW your sample code did not work without changing to `confm = np.array(...)`

Comment: With 5.1.0 and the inversion of the y-label removed I at least get identical graphs, but the wrong diagonal.
I added z = z[::-1] to invert this, which seems to make it fully work.

The only left-over quirk is that it refuses mixed datatypes.

Answer (score 0):

This works with the confm simply straight from scikit, without going through conversions. The only thing that still breaks it is mixing label data types:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
   

def plot_matrix(confm, class_names):

    z = np.round(confm, 2)
    
    z = z[::-1]
      
    fig = ff.create_annotated_heatmap(z,
                                      colorscale='reds',
                                      xtype='array',
                                      ytype='array',
                                      x=class_names,
                                      y=class_names,
                                     )
    
    

    fig.update_layout(
            title='Confusion matrix',
            width=600,
            height=600,
            margin=dict(pad=20),
            plot_bgcolor='white',
            xaxis=dict(title='Prediction',  # Prediction
                       showticklabels = True,
                       side='bottom',
                       tickmode='array',
                       tickvals=class_names,
                       ticktext=class_names),
            yaxis=dict(title='Truth',  # Truth
                       tickmode='array',
                       tickvals=class_names,
                       ticktext=class_names[::-1]
                      )
                    )


    fig.show()


truth = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'b'] 
pred = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a']
labels = ['a', 'b'] 

confm = confusion_matrix(truth, pred, labels)

plot_matrix(confm, labels)
```